# How to add search input jQuery $.tableSorter plugin?

Tags: jquery

i m using tableSorter plugin for reordering table items. But i need to put search input top of this tables too. What is the offer ?

The plugin is here. http://tablesorter.com/docs/

Thank you so much.

Comment: you question is not clear

Comment: Have you tried [datatables](https://datatables.net/) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this unofficial fork that implements many features to tablesorter: http://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/index.html

You can use `bindSearch` to add a search feature.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/3cegrho6/

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you to use DataTables pluggin its similar to tablesorter plus it has search, pagination etc..
https://www.datatables.net/examples/data_sources/dom.html

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you to use DataTables plugin:

**https://www.datatables.net/examples/data_sources/dom.html**

If you want to use tablesorter for some reason then use the below code.

**fiddle:http://jsfiddle.net/4mVfu/5313/**

**jquery:**

```
$(function(){
    $('table').tablesorter();
    $("#search").on("keyup",function(){
        var searchKey = $(this).val();
        if(searchKey === ""){
            $(".tablesorter tbody tr").show();
        }else{   
            $(".tablesorter tbody tr").hide();
            $(".tablesorter tbody tr td").each(function(){                
                if($(this).text().indexOf(searchKey) > -1){
                    if(!$(this).parent("tr").is(':visible')){
                        $(this).parent("tr").show();
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    });
});
```